# How to get the latest date from a list of tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, datetime, tuples

I have a list looks like this:

```
[(0, '2015-10-08'), (1, '2020-11-17'), (2, '2006-09-14'),....]
```

I want to return the one with the latest date, how can I achieve this?

I tried:

```
a= [(0, '2015-10-08'), (1, '2020-11-17'), (2, '2006-09-14')]
print(max(a))
```

but this returns `(2, '2006-09-14')` , I'm confused, why is this? Thanks.

Comment: As they are already in YYYY-mm-dd, just sort the string and pick the last item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default max function works on first element of tuple. You can set this to second element by `max(a, key=lambda x: x[1])`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
print(max(a, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x[1], '%Y-%m-%d')))
```

You can use the max() function with key parameter to get max element according to a function.

Comment: Hi thanks, looks like it also works without `datetime`.

Comment: You are right, datetime is not needed because the format is Y-M-D already. But it can be required for different situations.

Answer (score 0):

When comparing tuples, the default behavior is to compare their first element, and then the second element if there is a tie, and so on. So when you call `max([(0, '2015-10-08'), (1, '2020-11-17'), (2, '2006-09-14')])`, you get  `(2, '2006-09-14')` because it has the largest first element.

You need to pass a custom function to the `key` argument of the builtin [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function in order to make it compare on the dates:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> arr = [(0, '2015-10-08'), (1, '2020-11-17'), (2, '2006-09-14')]
>>> max(arr, key=lambda item: datetime.strptime(item[1], "%Y-%m-%d"))
(1, '2020-11-17')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use  `max(a)` it returns the maximum first element in your tuple which is 2. Hence, `max(a) = (2, '2006-09-14')`
I suggest you this code :

```
import numpy as np
list_dates=[]
for i in np.arange(len(a)):
    list_dates.append(a[i][1])
max(list_dates)
```

It returns

```
'2020-11-17'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code as you have used `max` function it is comparing the first element of each tuple and giving the result.

I hope the below code sample would satisfy your use case -

```
a= [(0, '2015-10-08'), (1, '2020-11-17'), (2, '2006-09-14')]
n=len(a)
max_date=a[0][1]
for i in range(1,n):
    date=a[i][1]
    if(max_date < date):
        max_date=date
print(max_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing `max(a)` is looking at the zeroth element and finding the max, which is 2. You want to only look at the elements with the dates in so you need `a[[i[1] for i in a].index(max([i[1] for i in a]))]`.

That might look a bit confusing because it's all on one line.

Essentially what it does is this:

You want to make a list `b` of only the date elements. `b = [i[1] for i in a]`.

Then find the index of the max of that list. `max_index = b.index(max([i[1] for i in a]))`, this returns '1', so we know it's the element at position 1.

Finally, you need to get `a[1]`, the element of a at position 1.

So all together it's `a[[i[1] for i in a].index(max([i[1] for i in a]))]`.